# Unable to determine the current version of FireFox after updated to 28.0

Tags: firefox, selenium

When I run my Selenium tests with Firefox 28.0 I get:

"An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to determine the current version of FireFox using the registry, please make sure you have installed FireFox correctly"

I successfully ran tests yesterday with Firefox.

I think Firefox auto-updated to 28.0 since yesterday.

Today I'm getting the above error.

I uninstall Firefox and reinstalled but I still get the same exception.

Selenium 2.40
Firefox 28.0
Gallio and MbUnit 3.4

Any ideas on how to fix? I suppose I could switch to IE for testing.

Ed

Comment: use selenium2.39 version and try!

Comment: Where is Firefox installed on your machine?

Comment: Try uninstalling Firefox and then re-installing it.  That's what I would do.

Comment: I tried Firefox 27.0. I tried Selenium 2.39. I get the same error. I installed FF under my login and as administrator. No Luck.

Comment: It's 2016 and we still have this issue lol. No luck for me.

Comment: I am using selenium 3.0.1 version. For this Firefox 47.0.1 is compatable. Still facing this error!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

The error was generated on the call to FireFoxBinary() constructor.

```
 DriverObj = New FirefoxDriver(New FirefoxBinary(), New FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
```

The call to FirefoxBinary worked for three weeks so I'm not sure why it decided to fail yesterday. Perhaps it was the auto-update by Firefox from 27 to 28.

The solution was to add the file path to the Firefox binary:

```
 DriverObj = New FirefoxDriver(New FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe"), New FirefoxProfile(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10))
```

Comment: Where to do the change ? I have dlls.

Comment: Did you get where to include this. Facing same issue.. Pls help.

Comment: When instantiating the `FirefoxDriver`, use an overload which takes a `FirefoxBinary` object. Set the `FirefoxBinary` constructor's argument to the full path and file of the Firefox Executable on your system. It is most likely to be located here: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this would be to manually add the registry key that is being searched for. Normal FireFox builds (non ESR) appear to place a key titled "CurrentVersion" with a string value of the version in the

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla FireFox

directory. Testing has shown me that when I place a key similar to this but with a string value of the ESR version installed on my system in this location Selenium will work. The caveat is that as this question is rather old I have tested with Selenium 3.0.1. If you would like to try this the your registry key should look like this without the quotes:

```
Name = "CurrentVersion" and 
Value = "45.6.0 ESR (x86 en-US)"
```

Please keep in mind that this solution will get you by in a pinch, but each time ESR updates you will need to go in and update the key value.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me mad, until i finally cracked it, here's the code that fixed mine:

```
        var options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```